# Can't create macro in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macros, record

I did this before but now I am unable to do it again.
I want to create a macro and short cut to untabify selected lines.
First , I select the lines I want to untabify.
Then I choose record temporary macro.
Then I select Edit - Advanced - Untabify Selected Lines.
Then I click stop recording.
In the Macro Explorer I have "TemporaryMacro" but if I undo my last action and run the macro, it doesn't do the untabify.

Here is the macro code:

```
Sub TemporaryMacro()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Untabify()
End Sub
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762194/macros-dont-run-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Those files are read only they cannot be edited.

Comment: You just need to run your text editor with admin rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by windows update KB2898869.
Uninstalling it allows macros to work again in Visual Studio.