# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate 64 bit Crashes soon after start Win 8-64 bit machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

devenv.exe Log shows the VS breaks soon after Macros package load successful. Hence by suspecting Macros, i followed [Macros don't run in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762194/macros-dont-run-in-visual-studio-2010). But issue still exist.

I uninstalled and cleared the registry using CCleaner. Installed it again but not successful. I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit machine. Is there anyone, came across this issue? Any solutions or work around?

" Edited after found the solution - I checked Event Viewer log, found that igdumb.dll is the faulting module."

Answer (score 1):

The issue is between the Intel graphics driver and WPF. So, I followed the work around from the link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2894215/you-experience-performance-issues--product-crashes--or-rendering-issue

That solves my issue. My Visual studio works as charm now!